# Memory corrupted across single-line function call?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, gdb

I am getting a seg fault from some code which accesses an array consisting of strings. The odd thing is I lose the memory across a one-line function call.

So this is my code:

```
class A {

    void method1(){

        std::cout << _myArray[ID] << std::endl;               //This outputs fine
        _pointerToObjectB->method2(ID, side);
    }

    std::array<std::string, 30000> _myArray;
    B* _pointerToObjectB;
};
```

In a different class:

```
class B {

    void method2(const int16_t ID, const int8_t Side) {
        std::cout << _objectA._myArray[ID] << std::endl;          //Seg fault
    }

    A _objectA;
};
```

GDB reports a seg fault, backtrace:

```
#0  0x00007ffff05cd81c in std::string::_M_data() const () from /debug/bin/../lib/libstdc++.so.6
#1  0x00007ffff05cd85a in std::string::_M_rep() const () from /debug/bin/../lib/libstdc++.so.6
#2  0x00007ffff05cdeb8 in std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(std::string const&) ()
   from /debug/bin/../lib/libstdc++.so.6
#3  0x00007fffe32f8bb1 in B<(short)-2, (short)1, (short)30000>::method2 (this=0x0, ID=362, Side=0 '\000')
#4  0x00007fffe32eafdf in A<(short)-2, (short)1, (short)30000>::method1 (this=0x2754400, ID=362, Side=0 '\000')
```

The pointer must be fine as it was able to invoke `method2()`. What else could be wrong?!

Its as if `_objectA` has been deleted across the call?

This seg fault is consistent, it happens every time I run the program. I'm at a bit of a loss what to do next.

Comment: `_pointerToObjectB` is not initialized. `this=0x0` in the debugger output is a dead giveaway.

Comment: @samgak The debugger says `ID=362`

Comment: You should provide a small self contained compilable example. The code that you provided is clearly not the whole picture. It appears that you aren't initializing the members of A fully. This is apparent because gdb reports that the this pointer is null when you hit method2().

Comment: where is the initialization of the members?

Comment: Each class has approximately 1,000 lines so I have to condense the problem to the fact the array access was fine before the function call and seg faulted immediately inside it.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik how can _pointerToObjectB not be initialized if it is invoking the method call to method2()?

Comment: ... which method is promptly crashing. Your program exhibits undefined behavior. You are observing one possible manifestation of undefined behavior. What exactly did you expect to happen instead, and why?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik if the pointer was null, I didn't expect a method invocation to take place? In other words I didn't expect GDB to recognise where the function call was intended if the pointer was null.

Comment: Why did you not expect the method invocation to take place? Which piece of documentation misled you thus?

Answer (score 3):

`_pointerToObjectB` is not initialized. `this=0x0` in the debugger output is a dead giveaway. –  Igor Tandetnik

A minor correction to Igor's answer: `_pointerToObjectB` is not pointing to an instance of `B`. It is `NULL`. It may be `NULL` by chance (it *really* isn't initialized), or it may have been initialized to `NULL` -- we don't know because you didn't show initialization code.

> if the pointer was null, I didn't expect a method invocation to take place?

That appears to be the root of your misunderstanding.

A *non-virtual* method invocation is *not at all* different from a regular function call. The compiler translates this:

```
Foo *foo = ...;
foo->Bar();
```

into this:

```
_ZN3Foo3Barv(foo);
```

where `_ZN3Foo3Barv` is just a label that the compiler attached to definition of the `Foo::Bar(void)` method. In fact, you could write above call in plain `C`, and it would work.

Virtual methods work differently, and calling a virtual method through a `NULL` pointer would likely behave as you expected -- would crash *before* landing on the method being invoked.